# Return redirect wont pass parameters

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

i cant find solution to this simple problem.
urls.py

```
path('board/<id>/', board, name="board"),
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        usuario = request.user
        last_board = Usuario.objects.filter(user=usuario.id).values_list("last_board", flat=True)
        if usuario.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/board/', last_board )
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

i tried with get, post, without a request.method but its just simple dont pass the arguments, i literally have the same line on another method and works perfectly.

Error

```
url returned: 127.0.0.1/8000/board/
TypeError at /board/
tablero() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `redirect`, you can use the *name* of the path, and then pass positional and/or keyword parameter.

Another problem is that you use [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter), this thus means that you retrieve a *collection* of objects (that can contain zero, one, or more `last_boards`. YOu should retrieve only one, so:

```
def index(request):
    usuario = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET' and usuario.is_authenticated:
        usr = get_object_or_404(Usuario, user=usuario.id)
        #  name of the view ↓
        return redirect('board', id=usr.last_board)
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, works perfectly and now i understand much better how redirect works!